# How if capture particular cell value

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have entered a date in Column A and column B.

```
   Column A  |    Column B   | Column C
---------------------------------------
   23/9/2019 |    19/9/2019. |
```

Now i am trying to get date in a `column c` which is greater. Which formula should I use?

Comment: Please specify the desired output, what exactly does "greater" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `MAX()` worksheet function.  It will give you the **greater** *(that is, the larger or most recent)* of the two values.

Just make sure the values are true Excel dates and not text values.

Comment: i didnt know that max function take date as well. thank you so much.